# How to remove a Section Break from Word?

Tags: onedrive, sharepoint, microsoft-word

I have a Word document on OneDrive with a bunch of empty pages delimited by ***Section Breaks***.
I would like to remove these empty pages. I tried delete, backspace, select and delete, unfortunately nothing worked out.
Any idea where I could find these ***Section Breaks*** and how to remove them and their corresponding pages?

[image]

### Update

Here's a screenshot with the paragraph ending activated (**Show/Hide ¶** on):
[image]

Comment: It's not clear why this question was posted here.  Are you still facing this problem? If so, first ask your self if what web application are you using to edit your document. If you are using Word online use [tag:word-online] instead of [tag:microsoft-word]. I don't think that [tag:onedrive] and [tag:sharepoint] are relevants.

Answer (score 1):

So I don’t have my computer here right now but if you’re able to pop open mobile I can walk you through what I did to recreate/solve the problem. It should work similarly on the web app just a different UI/UX.

- To recreate I went to ‘layout’ and added section breaks
- Then I tapped one, and chose ‘Select’ to highlight it
- I then hit the backspace key but not the Delete button in the pop up  menu (on mobile)

Using iPhone XS Max, Safari - Latest versions. If this isn’t helpful I can do the same for web app tomorrow.

[image]

Comment: I don't have **Section Break (Next Page)**. Only **Section Break**. As mentioned before, delete does not work.

Comment: True, you mentioned that delete didn’t work. I felt it was unclear if you had also highlighted it or just tried to delete from within the content area or dragged over to select but didn’t necessarily actually have it selected. I will open on my desktop now to see if I can gain any additional insights.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove Section Breaks by  highlighting the Formatting Marks for your document first. Here are the steps:

1. Select **Home**
2. Click on **Show/Hide ¶**
3. You will see **Section Break (Next Page)** mark at the places where there is a new break.
4. Place your cursor just before these Section Break marks, and press **Delete**.

This will remove the Section Breaks from the document.

*Note* : Doing so will naturally combine the contents before and after such breaks into a contiguous block.

Comment: I don't have **Section Break (Next Page)**. Only **Section Break**.